# SSRS nested IIF/CStr explanation

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, c-strings, iif-function

Could someone let me know if the IIF statement below means output any value that starts with a 4 please?

=IIF(LEFT(CStr(Fields!CLOCK_NUMBER.Value),1)="4",Fields!JOB_NO.Value, "")

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Ugh - am I the only one who's tired of all these ^^^^ lame MCVE comments and close voters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Starting from the middle and working outwards this expression is doing the following..

1. Get the value of the field CLOCK_NUMBER
2. Convert this to a string (the CSTR function)
3. Take the 1st character (LEFT function with 1 as the seconds parameter)
4. If the equals "4" return the Value that is in JOB_NO
5. Otherwise return an empty string

If this is not working for some reason, try converting the job_no to a string before returning, that way you ensure you always return a string (in case JOB_NO is numeric). You can simply wrap the job_no in a CSTR like this `CSTR(Fields!JOB_NO.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Translates to..."try to" convert the field `CLOCK_NUMBERS's` native value to a string and take the LEFT(1) most significant digit(s) and if that value is "4" then return the `JOB_NO` Fields's value. else return empty string.

So, it is, if the first digit is 4 then return `JOB_NO`.